# Google Maps JavaScript taking variable into a LatLng()

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to pass two variable to a piece of Marker code that draws the markers on the map i just don't know how to pass the variable what type must they be in order for me to achieve this heres what im trying to do:

```
double car = -23.363882;
double car2 = 126.044922;

position: new google.maps.LatLng(car,car2)
```

Comment: what problem your getting in this?

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, variables should be declared using [the `var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). I'm not sure where you got `double` from.

Here's how you draw a marker on a map:

```
var lat = -23.363882;
var lng = 126.044922;
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: theMap,
    position: latLng
});
```

I hate to say RTFM, but the API docs **do** spell out the answer to your question. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers

Answer (score 0):

car and car2 variables should be declared in the following manner : 
var car = -23.363882;
var car2 = 126.044922;

Note that Javascript doesn't use concrete types when declaring a variable.